# jQuery fadeOut > get/load > fadeIn

Tags: jquery, get, load, fadein, fadeout

Good evenin, basically my problem is, when trying to fadeOut  div, load by ajax the new content, and fadeIn that new content, my parent div will lose the "opacity:0" from fadeOut the moment the load/get is done, making my div flicker when fadeIn comes into play.

My question is if there's any way of disabling the style removal that executing load/get implies.

Best Regards

Comment: Have you already tried callback parameter from `.load()`? Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and search for "callback".

Comment: It would be helpful to see a fiddle of this, as I'm not aware of the behavior. Is it stripping the inline style on the container `div`? If so what happens if you add a css class with opacity 0 to that container `div` before you perform the `.load()`

Comment: @chiefGui still no good :\

Comment: @EdHinchliffe that won't work because at the end of fadeIn the style="opacity:1" won't be there anymore. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: you can remove the class in the callback after fadein.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Good idea but it will swap the problem to fadeOut, when the fadeOut is triggered it won't wait for it to end and it will set opacity 0 way before...

Comment: can you create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the issue?